# Como saber si hay un año entre fechas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
Nombre    Numero    Forma de Pago   FechaPago
Pablo      51312      Semestral     1/1/2021
Pablo      51312      Semestral     1/7/2021
Pablo      51312      Semestral     1/1/2022
```

lo que quiero hacer es agregar un campo comparando el FechaPago para ver si existe un año entre las mismas, el ejemplo de arriba es para las semestrales por ejemplo

pero tengo datos que por ejemplo son de 4 meses, trimestrales, y lo que quiero es hacer una validacion para todos esos y cuando sumen un año que me lo identifiquen con un 1 o un SI

los datos ya estan dentro de una tabla, el query es el siguiente

```
SELECT 
Nombre,Numero, FormaPago, FechaPago
FROM PlanDePago
WHERE Numero = '051312'
```

Comparto un ejemplo de el resultado que espero

```
Nombre  Numero  Forma de Pago   FechaPago   CumpleAño
Pablo   51312   Semestral        1/1/2021      No
Pablo   51312   Semestral        1/7/2021      No
Pablo   51312   Semestral        1/1/2022      SI
```

```
Nombre  Numero  Forma de Pago   FechaPago   CumpleAño
Pedro   46484   Trimestral       1/1/2021      No
Pedro   46484   Trimestral       1/4/2021      No
Pedro   46484   Trimestral       1/7/2021      No
Pedro   46485   Trimestral       1/10/2021     No
Pedro   46486   Trimestral       1/1/2022      SI
```

Si alguien me ayuda porfavor

Comment: No entiendo del todo el tema del trimestre o semestre... es un campo que alterará de alguna forma si cumple años o no? O solamente es un dato? Otra pregunta, el campo Número que tienes ahí, también es relevante? sirve como identificador de algo?

Comment: la tabla de ejemplo es una tabla de un plan de pago de un creditos, el campo numerico que sale ahi es para identificar un credito nada mas, lo que quiero es identificar los creditos que si su forma de pago es Semestral, y ha realizado los pagos durante un año, un campo que me identifique que en efecto ya cumplio un año de pagos, igual cuando es Trimestral, un campo que identifique que ese credito de forma trimestral ya tiene un año de pagos

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en los comentarios, intenta de la siguiente manera:

```sql
SELECT Nombre,Numero, FormaPago, FechaPago, 
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(yy,MIN(FechaPago),MAX(FechaPago)) = 1
            THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END CumpleAnio
FROM PlanDePago
WHERE Numero = '051312'
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que necesitas saber, es la fecha inicial del intervalo, es decir la primer `FechaPaGo` de cada grupo:

```
SELECT Nombre, 
       Numero, 
       MIN(FechaPago) 'FechaPagoInicial'
       FROM PlanDePago
       GROUP BY Nombre, Numero
```

Luego ya puedes integrar esta consulta para obtener la diferencia de cada fecha:

```
SELECT PP.Nombre,
       PP.Numero, 
       PP.FormaPago, 
       PP.FechaPago,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, FI.FechaPagoInicial, PP.FechaPago) > 0 THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END 'CumpleAño'
       FROM PlanDePago PP
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Nombre, 
                          Numero, 
                          MIN(FechaPago) 'FechaPagoInicial'
                          FROM PlanDePago 
                          GROUP BY Nombre, Numero
                 ) FI
                 ON PP.Nombre = FI.Nombre
                 AND PP.Numero = FI.Numero
```

Esto siempre midiendo el año por medio de fechas, pero ciertamente sabiendo en cada plan cuantos períodos completan un año, podrías numerar las filas y ver cuales llegan al total del plan, ej: trimestral = 4 semestral = 2, lo cual te evitaría seguramente usar la subconsulta.